# What does $(\mathbb{Z}_n^*)^2$ mean?

Tags: number-theory, notation

In a paper they write once, $(\mathbb{Z}_n^*)^2$. Is this the group of quadratic residues or is it something else?

Here the theorem:

Under the strong RSA assumption, given a modulus $n$, along with random elements $g, h \in (\mathbb{Z}_n^∗)^2$, it is hard to compute $w \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ and integers $a, b, c$ such that $w^c = g^a h^b$ and ($c \nmid a$ or $c \nmid b$).

Comment: How about a link to the paper? Is it about cryptography?

Comment: It could mean $\mathbb{Z}_n^*\times \mathbb{Z}_n^*$, i.e., the set of pairs of elements from $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$. A little bit of context might help.

Comment: Typically, $\mathbb Z_n^*$ would mean the _multiplicative group_ of the ring $\mathbb Z_n$, the set of integers $\{0,1,2,\ldots, n-1\}$ with arithmetic being done modulo $n$. The multiplicative group would, of course, be $\{1,2,\ldots, n-1\}$ with multiplication being done modulo $n$. I would suspect that $(\mathbb{Z}_n^*)^2$ is the Cartesian product $\mathbb{Z}_n^*\times \mathbb{Z}_n^*$ whose elements are of the form $(a,b)$ with $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$.

Comment: The multiplicative group would only be $\:\{1,2,...,n-1\}\:$ when $n$ is prime. $\hspace{1 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer Thanks for catching that. Unfortunately, it is too late to edit my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb Z_n^*$ is a mathematical notation for the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$.  In other words, it is the set of integers that are relatively prime to $n$, all taken modulo $n$ (excluding zero). The $*$ symbol is commonly used for denoting "the set of elements in the multiplicative group", which in this case means "the set of elements that are relatively prime to $n$".

Normally $\mathbb Z_n^*$ is treated as a multiplicative group, so it comes coupled with the multiplication operation modulo $n$.  (In contrast $\mathbb Z_n$ would denote the group of integers modulo $n$ under addition, or the field over the same set with both addition and multiplication.)

When such algebraic structures are raised to the power of two, it is an abbreviation for the Cartesian product of the underlying set with itself, in this case $\mathbb Z_n^* \times\mathbb Z_n^*$, i.e. the set of value pairs $(x,y)$ where both $x,y$ are integers in the range $1$ to $n-1$ and relatively prime to $n$.

Cartesian products of sets are also sets and might be coupled with one or more binary operations to form algebraic structures, such as fields and groups. In this case, the operations would be determined by context.

**Edit:** It should be noted that in mathematics, the $*$ symbol is more generally used for denoting a set excluding element zero. For instance, $\mathbb Z^*$ means the set of integers except $0$. However, it doesn't make sense to extrapolate this notation to finite sets such as $\mathbb Z_n^*$, except when $n$ is prime. If $n$ is composite, the set of integers $1$ to $n-1$ is not closed under multiplication, but the set of integers relatively prime to $n$ is. Hence, it is usually safe to presume $\mathbb Z_n^*$ denotes the (underlying set of the) multiplicative subgroup, unless explicitly stated otherwise.

Comment: The integers modulo $n$ (excluding zero) are not necessarily a group under multiplication. $\hspace{.58 in}$

Comment: I've always seen $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ as the group of units modulo $n$, even when that is not equal to $\:\mathbb{Z}_n-\{0\}\:$. $\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: Me too, but I consulted my text books in mathematics. The * symbol means "excluding zero", and does not necessarily entail that all elements are invertible under the implied operation. For instance, $(\mathbb Z^*,\cdot)$ means the set of non-zero integers under multiplication, which has all properties of a group except invertibility. I don't know what is the correct way of denoting the subgroup of integers relatively prime to the modulus.

Comment: I suppose one could follow [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_%28ring_theory%29#Group_of_units) and write $\:U\left(\mathbb{Z}_n\right)\;$. $\;\;$

Comment: I've fixed this answer for you.  The standard answer is that $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$ is the multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$.  There really is no other common usage for this (certainly not in cryptography).  Ricky Demer is 100% correct.

Comment: @D.W. $\;\;\;$ It's also my understanding that $\: 0\in \mathbb{Z}_1^* \:$, $\:$ rather than zero always being excluded.

Comment: @D.W.: Is my phrase "a mathematical notation" really correct after your edit? Should it be replaced by "used in cryptography to denote"?

Comment: @HenrickHellström: $\:$ Those things are correct, but they aren't what I was talking about. $\hspace{.37 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer: The group $(\mathbb Z_1,\cdot)$ is indeed the trivial group with just one element, which happens to be the element zero. Since it is a trivial group I don't think I have ever seen anyone use the notation $\mathbb Z_1^*$ for it (and fwiw and imho I don't see a need for it either).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have inserted the theorem which contains $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$. I think what they really mean is $(g, h) \in (\mathbb{Z}_n^∗)^2$, or?

Comment: @user4811: It looks that way, but perhaps more to the point, was there anything in the context of that theorem that led you to believe the notation could have anything to do with quadratic residues?

Comment: @HenrickHellström: I have looked a little bit around. The theorem was copied from another paper. In the original paper they have never used quadratic residues but Cartesian products. It makes all sense now! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @HenrickHellström: For a ring $R$, the notation $R^*$ denotes $R$ minus the divisors of zero. Recall that $x$ is a divisor of zero in $R$ iff there exists a non-zero element $y$ in $R$ such that $xy=0$. With this definition, all the special cases mentionned above such as $\mathbb{Z}_n$ or $\mathbb{Z}_1$ are also accounted for.

Comment: @minar: Thanks, that definition makes a lot of sense.