# How to select $g$ in Paillier Cryptosystem

Tags: public-key, homomorphic-encryption, paillier

For my cryptography class project in university I have selected `Paillier Cryptosystem` as a course project http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem#Key_generation

In key generation it says

> Choose two large prime numbers $p$ and $q$

I have selected $p$ = 11 and $q$ = 17, it also satisfies the condition

> $gcd(pq, (p-1)(q-1))=1$

which makes my $n$ = 187 and ${\lambda}$ = 80

and now in 3rd point it says

> Select random integer $g$ where $g \in (\mathbb{Z}_n^∗)^2$

now what does it mean $g \in (\mathbb{Z}_n^∗)^2$?

there is a question [What does $(\mathbb{Z}_n^*)^2$ mean?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8276/12583) but it doesn't make any sense to me

so the first question is **how can I select the random integer g?**

In 4th point it says

> Ensure $n$ divides the order of $g$ by checking the existence of the following modular multiplicative inverse: $\mu\ = (L(g^{\lambda}\mod n^{2}))^{-1} \mod n$

it further says

> where function $L$ is defined as $L(u) = \frac{u-1}{n}$ .

**can some one please help me to find out $g$ and $\mu$?**

- The public (encryption) key is $(n, g)$.
- The private (decryption) key is $(\lambda, \mu)$.

with any example or link that can guide me to a correct path.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The requirement is that your element $g$ is in $\mathbb{Z}_{n^2}^*$ and not in $(\mathbb{Z}_{n}^*)^2$.

The set $\mathbb{Z}_{n^2}^*$ is the set of integers smaller than $n^2$ that are relatively prime to $n^2$, i.e., you require an element $g$ from $\mathbb{Z}_{n^2}$ such that $\gcd(g,n^2)=1$.

$(\mathbb{Z}_{n}^*)^2$ on the other hand is the set of pairs $(a,b)$ such that $a$ and $b$ are from $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$.

You compute $\lambda=lcm(p-1,q-1)$ where $lcm$ is the [least common multiple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple). Then for your chosen $g$ you have to check whether $a=L(g^\lambda \bmod n^2)$ (where $L(u)=\frac{u-1}{n}$ ) has a multiplicative inverse modulo $n$ (is an element in $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$), i.e., you have to check whether $\gcd(a,n)=1$. If this is the case, then compute $\mu$ as $a^{-1} \bmod n$. Otherwise, try with another $g$ until this condition is satisfied.

Comment: thanks alot, what about the other part of the question? do you have any clue?

Comment: like how can I find μ

Comment: @zzlalani added more on that.

Comment: If I remember correctly, $g=n+1$ fulfills the necessary condition and is a viable option if you don't need a random generator.

Comment: @tylo, yes that's correct. at the cost of a larger $\lambda$ ($\varphi(n)$ instead of $lcm(p-1,q-1)$).

Comment: @DrLecter thanks once again, can you also guide me how can I find $μ$

Comment: @zzlalani Either you do as tylo says and compute $g$ as $g=n+1$ and then $\lambda=\varphi(n)$ and $\mu=\lambda^{-1} \bmod n$ (you can compute the multiplicative inverse modulo $n$ using [extended euclid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)). In this case you do not need to sample a random $g$. Or alternatively, you choose a random $g$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{n^2}^*$ and perform the checks as outlined in my answer and compute $\mu$ as the multiplicative inverse of $a$ modulo $n$ (again you can use extended euclid for this task).

Comment: also $a^{-1} \bmod n$ is equals to $a \bmod n  = 1 \bmod n$ right?

Comment: @zzlalani $a\cdot a^{-1} \equiv 1 \bmod n$. Thats how the multiplicative inverse of $a$ in $Z_{n}^*$ is defined. If you multiply an element with it's inverse it will give you the identity element.

Comment: @DrLecter I have gone through the complete process and generate the key by taking p and q as 5 and 7 respectively, where as my g is 36 (n+1) and λ is 24 and μ is 1/24, now for encryption I select m = 4 and r = 5 to keep it simple.. but when i encrypt it it outputs 50 and after decryption it outputs 0.0583333. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong but I think the issue is somewhere with L. please help!!

Comment: @zzlalani first, your $r$ is not co-prime to $n$, lets take $r=3$. Then 
your ciphertext is [1062](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2836%5E4+*3%5E35%29+mod+35%5E2). I'm not sure if your inverse is correct. You have to compute inverses in the ring modulo $n$, 
i.e., $24^{-1}$ should be 19 (an inverse $x^{-1}$ of $x$ modulo $n$ is defined such that $x\cdot x^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$). Then decrypting $1062$ yields [$4$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%28+1062%5E%7B24%7D+mod+35%5E%7B2%7D%29+-+1+%29+%2F+35%29+*+19+mod+35), which is correct.

Comment: @DrLecter Could you please explain/provide some reference why we can't use $\lambda=lcm(p-1,q-1)$ for $g=n+1$ and need to use Euler's totient function instead?